# Passing random numbers into an instance of an object

Tags: java, variables, math, random

my homework is asking me to do a math game in which I prompt the user to answer math questions and then show them the answer. I've created the `MathGame`class, but when I create an instance of `MathGame`, it asks me to put in two ints, which I don't know because I'm trying to generate them randomly.

**Question**: How do I get my random numbers from the class to pass into the instance of `MathGame`?

Below is the `MathGame` class

Underneath that is the main with the instance of `MathGame` I'm trying to figure out.

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MathGame {

    private int operand1;
    private int operand2;
    private int solution;

    public MathGame(int operand1, int operand2) {
        this.operand1 = operand1;
        this.operand2 = operand2;
    }

    public int genRandom1() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randNum = rand.nextInt(0) + 20;
        randNum = operand1;
        return operand1;
    }

    public int genRandom2() {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int randNum2 = rand.nextInt(0) + 20;
        randNum2 = operand2;
        return operand2;
    }

    public int getoperand1() {
        return operand1;
    }

    public int getoperand2() {
        return operand2;
    }

    public String question() {
        return "What is" + operand1 + operand2 + "?";
    }

    public String solution() {
        int solution = operand1 + operand2;
        return "The correct answer is: " + solution;
    }

}
```

I get an error in the instance of MathGame since I need to have two ints go through, but I don't know the ints obviously because they're supposed to be randomly generated, which I did in the class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MathGameMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        MathGame game1 = new MathGame();
    }

}
```

Comment: You have no default constructor. A default constructor has no arguments, and would be required to instantiate the instance you want.

Comment: In method ``genRandom1`` you are setting ``randNum`` to the value of ``operand1`` after generating the random value and saving it in ``randNum``, thus loosing the value. I believe that what you want to do is ``operand1 = randNum``. The same goes for ``genRandom2`` method.

Comment: Since `operand1` and `operand2` are integers whose value you don't know, should the single line in `public String question()` read `return "What is " + operand1 + " + " + operand2 + "?";` ? At present it looks as though it adds your two numbers to make a single one.

Comment: Alternately, just invoke MathGame with the proper constructor: `MathGame game1 = new MathGame( random1, random2 );`

Comment: @markspace but that doesn't work because I need two ints to be in the constructor.

Comment: @JordanPurinton So?  Make two ints and pass them in to the constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to change to something like this:

```
import java.util.Random;                                                     


public class MathGame {                                                      

  private int operand1;                                                      
  private int operand2;                                                      
  private int solution;                                                      

  public MathGame ()                                                         
  {                                                                          
    this.operand1 = getRandom();                                             
    this.operand2 = getRandom();                                             
  }                                                                          

  public int getRandom()                                                     
  {                                                                          
    Random rand = new Random();                                              
    int randNum = rand.nextInt(20);                                          
    return randNum;                                                          
  }                                                                          

  public int getoperand1()                                                   
  {                                                                          
    return operand1;                                                         
  }                                                                          

  public int getoperand2()                                                   
  {                                                                          
    return operand2;                                                         
  }                                                                          

  public String question()                                                   
  {                                                                          
    return "What is" + operand1 + " + " + operand2 + "?";                    
  }                                                                          

  public String solution()                                                   
  {                                                                          
    int solution = operand1 + operand2;                                      
    return "The correct answer is: " + solution;                             
  }                                                                          

}
```

You should generate the random numbers when the MathGame is initialized.  No need to pass numbers if you are going to randomly generate them.

Comment: But I want it all to be done within the class instead of the main.

Answer (score 0):

what do you want in this method

```
public int genRandom1()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randNum = rand.nextInt(0) + 20;
    randNum = operand1;
    return operand1;
}
```

and

```
public int genRandom2()
{
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randNum2 = rand.nextInt(0) + 20;
    randNum2 = operand2;
    return operand2;
}
```

you create a process and stored it to **randNum** but what you returned in the method was **operand2**. just return the **randNum** instead.

Comment: I want to just generate random numbers with those methods so they can be used in the main. My problem however, is that when I create an instance of MathGame, I am required to put two ints in the contractor and I want those ints to be randomly generated through the class. If that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

this is what i got from your comment,

1. call the MathGame object on Main class, and the constructor of MathGame returned 2 random number that stored on operand1 and operand2
2. the program will resulting a number by adding operand1 to operand2

**Solution**

```
import java.util.Random;

public class MathGame {

    private int operand1;
    private int operand2;
    private int solution;

    public MathGame ()
    {
        this.operand1 = genRandom();
        this.operand2 = genRandom();
    }

    public int genRandom()
    {
        Random rand = new Random();

        int randNum = rand.nextInt(0) + 20;

        return randNum;
    }

    public String question()
    {
        return "What is" + this.operand1 + " + " + this.operand2 + "?";
    }

    public String solution()
    {
        int solution = operand1 + operand2;

        return "The correct answer is: " + solution;
    }

}
```

in main class

```
import java.util.Scanner;


public class MathGameMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MathGame game1 = new MathGame();

        //question
        System.out.println(game1.question());

        // solution
        System.out.println(game1.solution());
    }

}
```